# Stay on same tab after refresh page

Tags: jquery

```
$(function () {
    // constants
    var SHOW_CLASS = 'show',
        HIDE_CLASS = 'hide',
        ACTIVE_CLASS = 'active';

    $('.tabs').on('click', 'li a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $tab = $(this),
             href = $tab.attr('href');


        $('.active').removeClass(ACTIVE_CLASS);
        $tab.addClass(ACTIVE_CLASS);

        $('.show')
           .removeClass(SHOW_CLASS)
           .addClass(HIDE_CLASS)
           .hide();

        $(href)
          .removeClass(HIDE_CLASS)
          .addClass(SHOW_CLASS)
          .hide()
          .fadeIn(550);
    });
});
```

I've tried the hiddenfield method but somehow I'm still unable to stay on the same tab after refresh. The above is my code from JS file.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: use `localStorage.setItem('currentTab', value)` to save the tab's name on change and `localStorage.getItem('currentTab', value)` to retrieve stored value after page load, i.e. in `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`

Answer (score 0):

You can add *anchors* to the links and use [`location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location) to grab the hash from the URL.

Doesn't need the `e.preventDefault();` if there is no `href` tag, and you can use [`data`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) attribute instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
            In React JS,

            I am using localstorage here to save the data.

            Add onClick function on each <li> 
            eg: onClick={()=>this.handleClick("your arg")}

            call this function: 
                handleClick=(arg)=>{
               localStorage.setItem("name",arg);
                }

        define state, this.state = {
                    history:true,
                    outgoing:false,
                    incoming:false,
                };

    in componentDidMount get the data from localstorage,

    eg:
      componentDidMount=()=>{
        let activeTab = localStorage.getItem("name");
      switch(activeTab){
            case 'History':
                this.setState({
                    history:true,
                    outgoing:false,
                    incoming:false,
                    confirmed:false
                })
                break;
                case 'Outgoing':
                        this.setState({
                            history:false,
                            outgoing:true,
                            incoming:false,
                            confirmed:false
                        })
                        break;
                        case 'Incoming':
                                this.setState({
                                    history:false,
                                    outgoing:false,
                                    incoming:true,
                                    confirmed:false
                                })
    }

than, use the ternary operator in two place

1> className={`nav-link js-animation-link btn btn-outline-light btn-wide 
    ${this.state.history ? "active":""}`}
2>  aria-selected={this.state.history ?"true" :"false"}

use the same ternary operator in "tab-content" as well.
```